# gts() from hts package: How to create strictly hierarchical time series, in order to apply the top down hierarchical forecasting method

Tags: r, time-series, hierarchical-data, forecasting

I'm interested to apply the top down approach as below
https://otexts.com/fpp2/top-down.html

```
y <- ts(matrix(rnorm(900),ncol=45,nrow=20))
blnames <- paste(c(rep("A",20),rep("B",25)), # State
                 rep(1:9,each=5), # County
                 rep(c("X","X","X","Y","Y"),9), # Industry
                 rep(c("a","b","c","a","b"),9), # Sub-industry
                 sep="")
colnames(y) <- blnames
gy <- gts(y, characters=list(c(1,1),c(1,1)))

gps <- rbind(
  c(rep(1,20),rep(2,25)), # State
  rep(1:9,each=5), # County
  rep(c(1,1,1,2,2),9), # Industry
  rep(1:5, 9), # Sub-industry
  c(rep(c(1,1,1,2,2),4),rep(c(3,3,3,4,4),5)), # State x industry
  c(rep(1:5, 4),rep(6:10, 5)), # State x Sub-industry
  rep(1:18, rep(c(3,2),9)) # County x industry
)

gy <- gts(y, groups=gps)
forecast(gy, method="tdgsa", fmethod="arima")# top down gross sohl method a
```

I've been trying to figure out how to define the strict hierarchy but it seems there's no examples on how to create one.
When trying to apply the top down method, I'll get the following error.

```
> forecast(gy, method="tdgsa", fmethod="arima")# top down gross sohl method a
Error: Argument method is not appropriate for a non-hierarchical time series.
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is, instead of using gts(), use hts().